# In my category landing page, 9 products are showing by default. how to make it 12?

Tags: product, magento2.3

In my category page, 9 products are showing by default. I want to make it 12 by default. how to make it 12?
[image]

Comment: can u share us any screenshot? plz so that it will be very easy

Comment: added the picture

Comment: Its not a product page @chandan its category landing (or) list page i will give you answer

Comment: Posted answer please try and let me know

Comment: You need to set default value for `Products per Page on Grid Default Value` in configuration

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below steps

```
Login to admin end -> Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Storefront -> Products per Page on List Allowed Values  -> Change the values as you required
```

For example: 12,24,....etc
 [image]

Answer (score 2):

go to Stores-> Configuration -> Catalog -> Storefront -> **Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values** change it to

12,18,24

AND

Set Defualt value in **Products per Page on Grid Default Value**

[image]